# How to get the Max value else latest max value

Tags: sql, mysql, date, max, mysql-5.7

| DATE | ACCOUNT | VALUE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-06-06 | 1234 | 100 |
| 2023-06-07 | 1234 | 120 |
| 2023-06-08 | 1234 | 80 |
| 2023-06-06 | 3456 | 40 |
| 2023-06-07 | 3456 | 60 |
| 2023-06-08 | 3456 | 80 |
| 2023-06-05 | 5648 | 600 |
| 2023-06-06 | 5648 | 800 |
| 2023-06-06 | 5648 | 650 |
| 2023-06-07 | 5648 | 0 |
| 2023-06-08 | 5648 | 0 |

I'm passing current date and getting the latest value from the table.

```
 set @curdate = '2023-06-08 ';
 select DATE,ACCOUNT,
        CASE WHEN DATE = @curdate THEN VALUE 
             WHEN VALUE = 0 AND DATE = @curdate THEN MAX(VALUE)
             ELSE 0
        END AS MAX_VALUE
from table ;
```

Actually I'm trying to get the latest value  and for example  if  value is not  present for current date then I have to get last maximum value for that account.

**output :**

| DATE | ACCOUNT | VALUE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-06-08 | 1234 | 80 |
| 2023-06-08 | 3456 | 80 |
| 2023-06-06 | 5648 | 650 |

Can anyone suggest me on this one?

Comment: What is the output you expect?

Comment: Which MySQL version?

Comment: @jarlh MYSQL 5.7

Comment: Can you add an account having only dates _before_ 2023-06-08, and an account having dates _before and after_ 2023-06-08, and adjust the expected result accordingly?

Comment: Can an account have several transactions with the same date?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the first previous value that is not equal to 0,(when the value on `@curdate` is equal to 0 or not exists) we could use a subquery and aggregate as the following:

```
set @curdate = '2023-06-08';

select max(DATE) as 'DATE',
       ACCOUNT,
       coalesce(nullif(max(case when DATE = @curdate then VALUE end), 0), 
                (select value from table_name d 
                 where d.ACCOUNT = t.ACCOUNT and
                       d.DATE < @curdate and
                       d. value > 0
                 order by d.DATE DESC
                 limit 1)
               ) MAX_VALUE
from table_name t
WHERE DATE <= @curdate and value > 0
group by ACCOUNT
```

[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/Y_LlHkHn)

Another approach, for mysql 5.7 you could simulate the row_number functionality as the following:

```
set @curdate = '2023-06-08';
set @rn =0;
set @acc = null;

select DATE, ACCOUNT, value 
  from
(
  select *,
     if(@acc<>ACCOUNT, @rn:=1, @rn:=@rn+1) rn,
     @acc:=ACCOUNT 
  from table_name 
  where DATE <= @curdate and value > 0
  order by ACCOUNT, DATE desc
) t
where rn = 1
```

[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/0jWpl9yY)

Comment: I have modified the question I need to get the latest value which is 700 for the account : 5648

Comment: The latest value or the maximum of the latest values?

Comment: This query returns the maximum previous value when the value is equal to 0 or not exists for the given date, and still gives the expected output after your update https://dbfiddle.uk/4jsMLQkq

Comment: I appreciate for answering my question but i want  to get the last value if it is not zero if I take MAX i'm getting 800 if i take min I get 600 but actually i want the last value before 0 which is 650 please see the updated question

Answer (score 3):

Using `ROW_NUMBER` we can try:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ACCOUNT ORDER BY DATE DESC) rn
    FROM yourTable
    WHERE VALUE <> 0
)

SELECT DATE, ACCOUNT, VALUE
FROM cte
WHERE rn = 1;
```

On earlier versions of MySQL:

```sql
SELECT t1.DATE, t1.ACCOUNT, t1.VALUE
FROM yourTable t1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT ACCOUNT, MAX(DATE) AS MAX_DATE
    FROM yourTable
    WHERE VALUE <> 0
    GROUP BY ACCOUNT
) t2
    ON t2.ACCOUNT = t1.ACCOUNT AND
       t2.MAX_DATE = t1.DATE
WHERE
    t1.VALUE <> 0;
```

Comment: It seems like OP wants one row per account. I.e. the subquery needs to be correlated. (Or something, the question lacks some clarity.)

Comment: @jarlh Post the latest edits, the question is lacking in clarity.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen looking to get the latest value for each account which means for the account : 5648 I need to get value: 700

Answer (score 1):

This can be done using this query :

The `cte` was used to get accounts with values, then we need to get the maximum value and the related date for accounts with value = 0, and finally we use `union all` to combine those datasets.

```
set @curdate = '2023-06-08';

with cte as (
  select ACCOUNT, DATE, max(VALUE) as max_value
  from mytable
  where DATE = @curdate
  group by ACCOUNT, DATE
)
select ACCOUNT, DATE, max_value as VALUE
from cte where max_value > 0
union all
select t.ACCOUNT, t.DATE, t.VALUE
from mytable t
inner join (
  select t.ACCOUNT, max(t.VALUE) as VALUE
  from cte c
  inner join mytable t on t.ACCOUNT = c.ACCOUNT
  where max_value = 0
  group by t.ACCOUNT
) as s on s.ACCOUNT = t.ACCOUNT and s.VALUE = t.VALUE
```

Result :

| ACCOUNT | DATE | VALUE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1234 | 2023-06-08 | 80 |
| 3456 | 2023-06-08 | 80 |
| 5648 | 2023-06-06 | 600 |

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/z696HqMF)